# ABC is a triangle. D is the center of BC . AC is perpendicular to AD. prove that $\cos(A)\cdot \cos(C)=\frac{2(c^2-a^2)}{3ac}$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

ABC is a triangle. D is the center of BC . AC is perpendicular to AD.  prove that $$\cos(A)\cdot \cos(C)=\frac{2(c^2-a^2)}{3ac}$$
problem and my attempts are shown in images. I cannot find the exact way to the answer.

[image: diagram]

[image: proof]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Is it $$\frac{2(c^2-a^2)}{3ac}$$

Comment: I changedd your $cos(c)$ to $cos(\gamma)$, because you are mixing up things otherwise. You should also be careful with the meaning of $cos(A)$ ...

Comment: ya answer is that one i couldn't type it. thanks for the advise.

Comment: thank you @JaideepKhare for the editing.

Comment: what are $$A,B,C$$? the internal angles as usualy denoted?

Comment: they have usual meaning.

Comment: If you draw $BE$ perpendicular to $CA$ extended, then since $AE=AC=b$, you have $cosA=\frac{-b}{c}$, and you can use cosines and cosine rule only to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so we have to prove that $$\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)=\frac{2(c^2-a^2)}{3ac}$$
we have $$\cos(\gamma)=\frac{2b}{a}$$ (I)
and $$\frac{\sin\left(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\gamma\right)}=\frac{-cos(\alpha)}{\cos(\gamma)}=\frac{a}{2c}$$
further we have
$$b^2+AD^2=\frac{a^2}{4}$$(II)
and $$AD^2=\frac{c^2}{2}+\frac{b^2}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4}$$ (III) therefore we get
$$a^2-c^2=3b^2$$
and $$\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)=-\frac{2b^2}{ac}=\frac{2(c^2-a^2)}{3ac}$$ if $$3b^2=a^2-c^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much.  can you help me for getting equation (III)

Comment: $$AD^2=a^2/4+c^2-2\frac{ac}{2}\cos(\beta)$$ and we find $\cos(\beta)$ from $$b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos(\beta)$$

Comment: I got it and Thank u very much again

Comment: this Problem is very fine and i will ask my students tomorrow

Comment: I don't know very much  about this web site. is there any way to help you to improve your account.

Comment: thank you sir. its a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Since $cosC=\frac{2b}{a}$, and $cosA=\frac{-b}{c}$, then $$cosA*cosC=\frac{-2b^2}{ac}$$Further,$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2
bc*cosA$$ Substituting $\frac{-b}{c}$ for $cosA$, and transposing gives$$3b^2=a^2-c^2$$From this we get$$-3b^2=c^2-a^2$$or$$\frac{-2b^2}{ac}=\frac{2(c^2-a^2)}{3ac}=cosA*cosC$$